# Iwasawa decomposition on unitary group of anisotropic kernel

Tags: algebraic-groups, automorphic-forms

Let $E/F$ be a quadratic extension of number fields. If $V$ is a hermitian space over $E$, let $V=X+V_0+Y$ be its Witt decomposition, where $X,Y$ are maximal totally isotropic subspaces and $V_0$ is anisotropic kernel of $V$ respectively.

Let $P(X)$ be the parabolic subgroup of $U(V)$ stabilizing $X$.
Then we can decompose $U(V)=P(X)K$ where $K$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $U(V)$.

I am wondering what is the Iwasawa decomposition of $U(V_0)$. How can we decompose it?
I also want to know what is the parabolic subgroup of $U(V_0)$.

Any comments will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Unless I misunderstand something here... $U(V_o)$ is compact, no? And has no proper ($F$-rational) parabolics.

Comment: @Paul, You are right! I think there is no proper parabolic and so no proper Iwasawa decomposition. Thank you very much for comment.

Comment: @Paul, from your comment, I think that $U(1)$ has no proper parabolic subgroup. Right?

Comment: Right: with a non-degenerate $E$-one-dimensional space, the corresponding unitary group has no proper parabolics... because it has no non-trivial isotropic subspaces.

Comment: @Paul, thank you for clear explanation. I always learn much from your comment and answers!:)